# Sitecore copied item displaying wrong content

Tags: content-management-system, sitecore

I'm new to sitecore have been tasked with creating some ppc landing pages for a client who's developer has moved on.

Their previous developer had created several of these pages in the past and the content is very similar so I have copied one of the previous pages and changed the content.

The problem is that the copy is still referencing the content of the original page, i know this as if i change the content of the original the copy also changes too.

The pages sub items are a mix of rich text fields and custom sublayouts.

Have I done something wrong or is this a bug? Can anyone suggest a fix?

Id imagine something like the reference to the subitems in the database has not changed from original.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did you copy the previous page? In Sitecore you should be able to use either the Copy or Duplicate command, and be able to change the copied item without the original being changed (our content editors have a habit of doing this as well).

My guess would be that the sublayouts are pointing at a specific item, rather than the Context item, but that would be hard to say without code or ascx snippets.

Comment: Its fixed! After what you said about specific references i poked around a bit in the presentation menu of the item and it turns out that under the layout->details menu the sub items were still set to be pointing to the original content. Thanks!